# Type Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable imprimir matrices

Tags: python-3.8

Saludos para todos

Estoy entrandole al mundo de la programacion voy por la tematica de arreglos, y copie tal cual un ejercicio que vi para imprimir matrices pero al momento de ejecutar mes sale el error al momento de llegar a linea del print(matriz[i][j])

Espero puedan ayudarme, este es el codigo:

```
Escribe un programa que lea una matriz de longitud n x m, luego imprime la matriz en consola

rows = int(input("Digite el numero de filas: "))
cols = int(input("Digite el numero de columnas: "))

matriz = []
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        dato = int(input("Ingresa la posicion ["+str(row)+"]["+str(col)+"] : "))
        matriz.append(dato)
        
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print(matriz[i][j], end= " ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probando tu código en consola, di a rows y a cols el valor de 2.
Cuando introduces los valores para matriz y luego los imprimes, el valor de matriz se ve de esta forma.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Cuando intentas acceder a matriz[i][j] estás intentando acceder a una lista dentro de otra lista.
Para que te funcionara matriz[i][j] tu matríz en vez de verse [1, 2, 3, 4]
tendría que ser algo del estilo:

```
ejemplo = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
```

y cuando accedieras a la posición [0][0] (por ejemplo), el resultado sería 0, primer valor de la lista principal [0,1,2,3] y después primer valor de esta segunda lista: 0

Lo que podrías hacer para sacar los valores de matriz, simplemente podrías recorrer esta lista de esta forma:

```
for m in matriz:
   print(m)
```

Suerte!

Comment: Hola Carmen, gracias por tu respuesta, pero mas que el valor de la casilla quisiera aprender a imprimir la matriz completa sin corchetes, y si puedes compatirme documentacion para leer sobre manejo de arrays te agradeceria

Comment: Te dejo varios enlaces para que puedas leer un poco más sobre matrices y veas todo lo que se puede hacer con ellas. [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) , [Estructuras de datos](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html), [Matrices en python](https://www.diegocalvo.es/matrices-en-python/)

Answer (score 0):

El error "Type Error: '`int`' object is not subscriptable" se produce cuando se intenta acceder a un entero como si fuera un objeto subscribible, como una lista o un diccionario.

Solución:

```
def my_matrix():
matrix = []

rows = int(input("Enter rows: "))
cols = int(input("Enter cols: "))

for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([0] * cols)

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        matrix[r][c] = int(input("Enter position %d, %d : " % (r, c)))
        print(matrix, end=" ")
    print()
```

Este código crea una matriz con las columnas que le indiques y los valores iniciales en cero y luego le pide al usuario rellenarla.

Comment: Hola kemilbeltre, al momento de ejecutar el codigo como lo indicaste se me imprime la matriz varias veces https://ibb.co/C6Yf9MM como se ve en la imagen, me ayudaria comprender porque ocurrio

Answer (score 0):

experimentando logre obtener el resultado que deseaba, les comparto mi respuesta:

```
from os import system
system('cls')

rows = int(input("Digite el numero de filas: "))
cols = int(input("Digite el numero de columnas: "))

matriz = []
for row in range(rows):
    matriz.append([])
    for col in range(cols):
        dato = int(input("Ingresa la posicion ["+str(row)+"]["+str(col)+"] : "))
        matriz[row].append(dato)

a = "|"+'\t'
for row in range(len(matriz)):
    for col in range(len(matriz)):
        a += str(matriz[row][col])+'\t'
    print(a+"|")
    a = "|"+'\t'
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que agregas los datos es incorrecta, pues todo lo agregas a una única lista, y una matriz se compone por n listas. El código debería quedar así:

```py
#pedimos datos
rows = int(input("Digite el numero de filas: "))
cols = int(input("Digite el numero de columnas: "))


matriz = []
for row in range(rows):
    fila =[] #aqui se almacenara los datos de la fila
    for col in range(cols):
        dato = int(input(f"Ingresa la posicion [{row}][{col}] : "))#usamos f-strings
        fila.append(dato)#agregamos el dato a la fila
    matriz.append(fila)#agregamos la fila a la matriz

#iteramos
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print(matriz[i][j], end= " ")
    print()
```

Y da como resultado

```py
Digite el numero de filas: 2
Digite el numero de columnas: 3
Ingresa la posicion [0][0] : 1
Ingresa la posicion [0][1] : 2
Ingresa la posicion [0][2] : 3
Ingresa la posicion [1][0] : 4
Ingresa la posicion [1][1] : 5
Ingresa la posicion [1][2] : 6

1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

También podemos simplificar.

```py
for row in matriz: # se puede simplificar el ciclo for
    #unimos los datos mediante |
    print("|".join(str(r) for r in row for row in matriz))
```

**resultado**
Con la misma entrada

```py
1|2|3
4|5|6
```